# Altern thread print C

Tags: c, mutex

I'm looking to print some times (nbFois) with threads. I did it but there is an issue with the following code. This is only working if all the threads got the same nbFois times.

Here this is working with nbAffichage[i] = 5 foreach thread. 
But if the nbAffichage is random (ex, the first one is 3...the second is 6); then when the first one end the second can't start.

```
/* Lancer les threads afficheurs */
  for (i = 0; i < nbThreads; i++) {
    //nbAffichages[i] = rand() % NB_AFFICHAGES;
    nbAffichages[i] = 5;
    if ((etat = pthread_create(&idThdAfficheurs[i], NULL,
                               thd_afficher, &nbAffichages[i])) != 0)
      thdErreur(etat, "Creation afficheurs", NULL);
  }
```

The print function

```
void *thd_afficher (void *arg) {
  int i, j, nbLignes;
  int *nbFois = (int *)arg;
  int monMut=tMut.indiceT[iAffiche];
  iAffiche=(iAffiche+1)%nbThreads;
  for (i = 0; i < *nbFois; i++) {
    nbLignes = rand()% (*nbFois);
    //nbLignes = 3;
    //l'affichage est trop rapide pour voir la différence
    pthread_mutex_lock (&tMut.m[monMut]);//demande accès
    for (j = 0; j < nbLignes; j++) {
      printf("Thread %lu, j'affiche %d-%d--------%d lignes\n", pthread_self(), i, j,nbLignes);
      usleep(10);
    } 
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&tMut.m[(monMut+1)%nbThreads]);//rend accès 
  }
  /* Se terminer sans renvoyer de compte-rendu */
  pthread_exit((void *)NULL);
}
```

The global thread structure

```
typedef struct ThreadId ThreadId;
struct ThreadId
{
    int indiceT[NB_THREADS_MAX];
    pthread_mutex_t m[NB_THREADS_MAX];
};

ThreadId tMut;
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: The whole code

```
/* nbThread affichent un message a l'ecran
   Parametre du programme : nbThread
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NB_THREADS_MAX  20
//#define NB_FOIS         2


typedef struct ThreadId ThreadId;
struct ThreadId
{
    int indiceT[NB_THREADS_MAX];
    pthread_mutex_t m[NB_THREADS_MAX];
};

ThreadId tMut;//variable de structure avec le tableau de threads et d'indice correespondant
//Mutex ayant le droit d'écrire au début
int iAffiche=0;
int nbThreads=-1;
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Afficher un message d'erreur en fonction du code erreur obtenu
*/
void thdErreur(int codeErr, char *msgErr, void *codeArret) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%s: %d soit %s \n", msgErr, codeErr, strerror(codeErr));
  pthread_exit(codeArret);
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Fonction executee par un thread : afficher un message un certain nombre
  de fois nbFois a l'ecran, nbLignes lignes de messages ou nbLignes et
  genere aleatoirement
  Parametre de creation du thread : nbFois, le nombre d'affichages
*/
void *thd_afficher (void *arg) {
  int i, j, nbLignes;
  int *nbFois = (int *)arg;
  int monMut=tMut.indiceT[iAffiche];
  iAffiche=(iAffiche+1)%nbThreads;
  for (i = 0; i < *nbFois; i++) {
    //nbLignes = rand()% (*nbFois);
    nbLignes = 3;
    //l'affichage est trop rapide pour voir la différence
    pthread_mutex_lock (&tMut.m[monMut]);//demande accès
    for (j = 0; j < nbLignes; j++) {
      printf("Thread %lu, j'affiche %d-%d--------%d lignes\n", pthread_self(), i, j,nbLignes);
      usleep(10);
    } 
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&tMut.m[(monMut+1)%nbThreads]);//rend accès 
  }
  /* Se terminer sans renvoyer de compte-rendu */
  pthread_exit((void *)NULL);
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#define NB_AFFICHAGES 10

int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
  pthread_t idThdAfficheurs[NB_THREADS_MAX];
  int i, etat;

  int nbAffichages[NB_THREADS_MAX];
  if (argc != 2) {
    printf("Usage : %s <Nb de threads>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  }

  nbThreads = atoi(argv[1]);
  if (nbThreads > NB_THREADS_MAX)
    nbThreads = NB_THREADS_MAX;

  //initialisation des mutex
  for (int k = 0; k < nbThreads; k++){
    tMut.indiceT[k]=k;
    pthread_mutex_init(&tMut.m[k],NULL);//tout les mutex init à 1
    if(k!=0){
      pthread_mutex_lock (&tMut.m[k]);//On retire l'accès à tous les mutex sauf le premier
    }
  }


  /* Lancer les threads afficheurs */
  for (i = 0; i < nbThreads; i++) {
    //nbAffichages[i] = rand() % NB_AFFICHAGES;
    nbAffichages[i] = 5;
    if ((etat = pthread_create(&idThdAfficheurs[i], NULL,
                               thd_afficher, &nbAffichages[i])) != 0)
      thdErreur(etat, "Creation afficheurs", NULL);
  }

  /* Attendre la fin des threads afficheur car si le thread principal
    - i.e. le main() - se termine, les threads fils crees meurent aussi */
  for (i = 0; i < nbThreads; i++)
    if ((etat = pthread_join(idThdAfficheurs[i], NULL)) != 0)
      thdErreur(etat, "Join threads afficheurs", NULL);

  printf ("\nFin de l'execution du thread principal \n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see `iAffiche` being defined anywhere. Also `int monMut=tMut.indiceT[iAffiche]; iAffiche=(iAffiche+1)%nbThreads;` is not atomic,so you might get multiple threads with the same iAffiche.

Comment: What is 'iAffiche' and where is it declared, (storage class?). Why does each thread have it's own mutex, (pointless)?  Why are those mutex protecting just a print loop, (stdout has an internal lock anyway)?

Comment: I added the all code at the end

Comment: As Davis says in answer, you are misuing mutex for a competely unsuitable purpose.  Try semaphores instead, passing back and forth a 'run now' token/unit.

Answer (score 1):

You have a race condition on the assignments to `iAffiche`.  Even assuming that goes well, your threads then lock "their own" mutex (`monMut`) but then unlock their neighbor's!  It looks like you want to pass a token down the line (which could very well fail when the threads want to loop different numbers of times), but you just can't use mutexes like that at all.

You might try an array of [semaphores](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_init.html) instead.  Initialize them to 0 except for the first thread's, which make 1.  Then, looping the *same* number of times across all threads, each thread waits on its semaphore, does its work (or does nothing if its `nbAffichages` values is too small), and then ups the semaphore of the next thread.  You end up in the initial state again, with the semaphore vector being (1,0,0,...).

Comment: I'm suppose to print the first message of thread 1...then the first message of thread 2. Then the second message of thread 1....then the second message of thread 2. --> If I got nbAffichage = 2 for both thread this is fine....but if the second one is nbAffichage = 4...this isn't working anymore. I see why...but I don't see how I can fix it.

Comment: I think your testing is giving you a false impression that the variation in `nbAffichage` is the main problem.  The simplest (if not very efficient) solution is a barrier that all threads join _N_ times even if they only print _n_ < _N_ times.

Comment: Ok, but how can I do that ? In fact this is just a simple exercice, there is no real application behind and I guess there will be better way to do this kind of things than using mutex. Thanks

Comment: @Minirock: I think I was actually thinking of the wrong primitive.  I've updated the answer.